# Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined in javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am writing modular javascript code. I wrote a basic calculator with two inputs and four buttons which performs arithmetic operations. When I run my it shows this error in console.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: add is not defined`

This happens for all buttons. How can I fix this and why it does not work?

Here is my **[code](http://jsfiddle.net/gmC94/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up variables and object properties. Javascript never implicitly looks up object properties - it's always a variable lookup with the exception of global object and `with`-statement.

So specify the object:

```
    calculation: function(operator) {
        if(operator == 'add')
            return this.add(valone, valtwo);
        else if(operator == 'sub')
            return this.sub(valone, valtwo);
        else if(operator == 'mult')
            return this.mult(valone, valtwo);
        else
            return this.div(valone, valtwo);
    }
```